# ExpressJS Variable Number of parameters at the end

Tags: node.js, parameters, express, request, optional-parameters

I want my express app to match requests with both `file/a` and `file/a/b/c`, the number of variables after the `file/` is at least 1.

I tried this:

```
app.get('/file/:path?*', function(req,res){
    res.send(req.params.path);   
});
```

However the result is:

```
$ curl localhost:3000/file/a
a
$ curl localhost:3000/file/a/b
a
```

How can I get the whole query by not using `req.query.splice(1)` ? I want the code to be more readable, this splice can be easily forgotten during maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at their [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB), there is a line about it:

Regular expressions may also be used, and can be useful if you have very specific restraints, for example the following would match "GET /commits/71dbb9c" as well as "GET /commits/71dbb9c..4c084f9".

```
app.get(/^\/commits\/(\w+)(?:\.\.(\w+))?$/, function(req, res){
  var from = req.params[0];
  var to = req.params[1] || 'HEAD';
  res.send('commit range ' + from + '..' + to);
});
```

This should solve your problem :)